# How do you use a Custom Model Manager method for a related Many-to-Many model field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a small project, mostly for learning, and I am running into an issue with accessing expected custom model manager methods on some related M2M type models. The application I am trying to implement is a travel calculator, that can determine total fuel requirements and weights for all vehicles in a particular trip.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum

# Create your models here.

class TripManager(models.Manager):

    def get_vehicle_weight(self):
        return self.get_queryset().all().aggregate(total_weight=Sum('vehicle__weight'))


    def get_vehicle_fuel(self):
        return self.get_queryset().all().aggregate(total_fuel=Sum('vehicle__fuel'))

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    """A vehicle may belong to multiple businesses and multiple trips at once."""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="The common name of the vehicle.")
    fuel_capacity = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text="The total fuel capacity in gallons.")
    burn_rate = models.FloatField(default=0, help_text="The burn rate of fuel in gal/h.")
    weight = models.FloatField(default=0, help_text="The weight of the vehicle in pounds.")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Business(models.Model):
    """"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="The name of the business.")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class EmployeeType(models.Model):
    """Employee types can belong to many businesses."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="The title/role of a type of employee.")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name      


class Trip(models.Model):
    """A trip will be the primary object, composed of other objects that are associated with the trip."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    vehicles = models.ManyToManyField(Vehicle, through="TripVehicle", through_fields=('trip', 'vehicle'),)
    employee_types = models.ManyToManyField(EmployeeType, through="TripEmployeeType", through_fields=('trip', 'employee_types'),)
    businesses = models.ManyToManyField(Business)
    objects = TripManager()

    class Meta:
        base_manager_name = 'objects'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TripVehicle(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()


class TripEmployeeType(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee_types = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    trip = Trip.objects.all()
    
    context = {
        'trip' : trip,

    }

    return render(request, 'home.html', context=context)
```

The above 'home' page is just for my testing. I've pre-populated the DB with some basic vehicles, businesses, and employee types. However, when navigating to the 'home' url, I get the below error:

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_vehicle_weight'

I am expecting to be able to create a 'trip' instance, then determine the sums of every vehicle attribute * the quantity of that type of vehicle for each trip. However, accessing the fields through 'trip.vehicles.get_vehicle_weight()' does not work.

What I expect to see:

```
# 3 cars with a weight of 1500 lbs each
trip.vehicles.get_vehicle_weight()
{'total_weight' : 4500}
```

What am I messing up with my implementation?

Comment: `get_vehicle_weight` can only be used on trip managers/querysets. So something like `Trip.objects.get_vehicle_weight()`

Comment: @bdbd I just made that adjustment in my view. It returns: Exception Type: AttributeError, Exception Value: Manager isn't accessible via Trip.

Comment: should be `Trip.objects`. `objects` is the manager

Comment: @bdbd Outstanding, this worked. I think the key takeaway is that I was trying to call the function on the wrong object. 

I was attempting to:
```variable = Trip.objects.all()
summary = variable.objects.get_vehicle_weight()```